# Troubleshooting css background-image not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the code snippet below. I am expecting the div to have that background logo. It's not happening. All js files are loaded correctly as other parts of the page work fine.

Two questions:

1- Using a network sniffer I don't see a request for logo.png. Possible reasons why?

2- Is there a way to know what url path the browser is using without using a network sniffer? I wanted to know if I should use `./` or `../` or whatever for the correct full path.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").css("background-image", "SomeLongMultiLevelPath/logo.png" );
    });

</script>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: idk, but shouldn't the url be `url(images/image.png)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#test").css("background-image", "url(SomeLongMultiLevelPath/logo.png)" );
```

... assuming your image path is right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so it was as I said: `url(SomeLongMultiLevelPath/logo.png)`
As for the directory, the dots are used to go up by one level:

```
//Home
// Dir1
//// Image.png url(../Dir1/image.png)
// Dir2
//// Yourpage.html
```

Comment: The second question was about how to know what's the full url the browser is using for a certain request (I know now). it's not what the dots mean.